# Simple Multiple Product Links in .htaccess file are not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$1&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ product2.php?cid=$1&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ product3.php?bid=$1&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]
```

Can't access product2.php or product3.php files...

Please help...

Comment: Can you add four spaces before each of your code lines? It'll format it into a codeblock, which is easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

All of your `RewriteRule` regular expressions are the same, so it will only match the first time, transform the URL to `product.php?pid=$1&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]`, and then do nothing else (The `L` flag specifies it won't match any more rules for that run, then after it rewrites the URL to `product.php`, `product.php` will not match any of the other rules on the next pass).

Additionally, there's no need to add `&%{QUERY_STRING}` if you pass the `QSA` flag, as this automatically appends the query string to the modified query string it gets from your `RewriteRule`.

I understand that you expect it to access those other two pages, but you'll need to describe what input URLs should map to each particular file for anyone to be able to help you further than this.